# Python None list size

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was just checking the size of some datatypes in Python 3 and I observed this.

```
import sys

val = None
print(sys.getsizeof(val))
```

The output was `16` as expected.

I tried making a list of 1000 locations of `None` and I expected the size to be `16*1000 = 16000` or more. But the result I got was different.

```
import sys

val = [None]*1000

print(sys.getsizeof(val))
```

The output was `8064`. Nearly the half of the size I expected.

What is the reason for this.? Why memory allocated is less.?

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` returns only the size of the *container* (so, the container overhead and for the list the array of Py_Object pointers, on a 64-bit system, 8 bytes per pointer), not the objects inside the list. In this case, however, since `None` is a singleton, the total size is simply `sys.getsizeof(val) + sys.getsizeof(None)`. In general, if a list references all unique objects, you have to get `sys.getsizeof(my_list) + sum(map(sys.getsizeof, my_list))`. Often, it is between these two extremes.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Great Explanation. Thanks

Comment: Note, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof): "Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to." It also provides a [link to a recursive sizeof recipe](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504) which will handle most complex objects (for example, caching based on identity).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import sys

val = None

print(sys.getsizeof(val))

Answer:

16

val = []

print(sys.getsizeof(val))

Answer: 

72

val = [None]

print(sys.getsizeof(val))

Answer:

80

so [None]*1000 = 1000* 8 + 72 = 8072
```

Note: *No of bytes may vary depending on the environment*

Comment: On my system, `sys.getsizeof([]) == 64`, like in the OP. (Though I guess it varies.)

Comment: You're undercounting by 8 bytes here.

Answer (score 5):

There is just a single `None` object referenced a thousand times.  So the situation is this:

```
l[0]   ----> None
         /    ^
l[1]   -/     |
….            |
l[999]  -----/
```

And not this:

```
l[0]   ----> None

l[1]   ----> None
….
l[999] ----> None
```

This is more visible when repeating a mutable object, like this:

```
>>> l = [set()] * 3
>>> print(l)
[set(), set(), set()]
>>> l[0].add(1)
>>> print(l)
[{1}, {1}, {1}]
```

There is just a single, shared `set` object referenced three times, so changes to the set at `l[0]` also affect `l[1]` and `l[2]`.

Python data structures such as `list`, `set` and `dict` are reference-based.  In your case, most of the 8064 bytes you observed come from the object references (8 bytes per list element).

Comment: So what if I used a list and appended None to 1000 loations.?

Comment: Same result because there is only a single `None` object.

Comment: @SreeramTP `None` is a singleton, the same with `True` and `False`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Got it. Thanks